# Get object instance from HtmlHelper

Tags: model-view-controller, lambda, types, html-helper

Using the following code in an htmlhelper gives me some metadata.
It even has the container type.
What I want is the container instance. In the expression

```
x => x.FirstName
```

I want to get at the x instance.

Is there any way to do that?

```
    public static MvcHtmlString DisplayEditorFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, string templateName, string htmlFieldName, object additionalViewData)
    {
        var result = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);
        ...
    }
```

result has the type, and a host of other information, but not the instance.
The expression itself must have that bound in the body. How do I tease it out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was stupid.

```
html.Model contains the object instance.
```

moreover

```
var value = expression.Compile().Invoke(html.ViewData.Model);
```

will give you the value of the evaluated model instance using the lambda.